# How to inject local script with require statements into Puppeteer page

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to crawl a webpage. I would like to parse the URL within the page, among other things. I get that I can move the functionality out of `page.evaluate`, but that is beside the main question. The question is how you inject an arbitrary script onto the page so you can use the variables/functions from the script within `page.evaluate`.

In my case, I am using [lil-uri](https://github.com/lil-js/uri). I have basically this:

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
var URL = require('lil-uri')

puppeteer.launch().then(browser => {
  browser.newPage().then(page => {
    page.goto('https://foo.com').catch(onerror).then(() => {
      page.evaluate(fetchLinks).catch(onerror)
    })
  })
  // })
})

function onerror(err) {
  console.log('ERRR', err)
}

function fetchLinks() {
  var linkEls = document.querySelectorAll('a')
  var links = []

  for (var i = 0, n = linkEls.length; i < n; i++) {
    var el = linkEls[i]

    // PARSE URL
    var url = parseUrl(el.getAttribute('href'))

    links.push(url)
  }

  return links

  function parseUrl(href) {
    // REF THE URL LIBRARY
    var url = URL(href)
    var url2 = url.path()
    var query = []
    var q = url.query()
    if (Object.keys(q).length) {
      // query.push(...)
    }
    if (query.length) {
      url2 += '?' + query.join('&')
    }
    return url2
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because the `require('lil-uri')` is in the scope of the Node.js script, while it is really being used in the context of `page.evaluate`.

The question is, how to include the `parseUrl` and `URL` functions in the page properly, so they can be used within the context of `page.evaluate`.

Also, as you can see I put the `parseUrl` function *within* the `fetchLinks` function, which is not ideal because I can't reuse it between other functions I evaluate on the page. I would like to be able to do something like `window.parseUrl = parseUrl` in the context of `page.evaluate`, but I wasn't sure how to do that either. Wondering if one could show how to do those two things:

1. How to load a local external script into the puppeteer page.
2. How to load functions onto the window of the puppeteer page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`page.exposeFunction`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) to expose a function from the Node.js environment to the page itself. To quote the docs:

> The method adds a function called `name` on the page's `window` object. When called, the function executes `puppeteerFunction` in node.js and returns a Promise which resolves to the return value of `puppeteerFunction`.

**Code sample**

The code below will expose your function `parseUrl` to the page. You can then call the function via `window.parseUrl` from within the `page.evaluate`.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function parseUrl(href) {
    // ...
    return '...';
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.exposeFunction('parseUrl', href => parseUrl(href));

    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        const url = 'http://...';
        const parsedUrl = await window.parseUrl(url);
    });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

**A sidenote regarding the parsing of URLs**

This is not directly related to your question, but you might not necessarily need to parse the URL inside of the Node.js environment. There is the JavaScript API [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for that, which allows you to parse URLs inside the browser itself like this:

```js
const url = new URL('http://www.example.org/path123');
console.log(url.pathname); // will print: /path123
```

Depending on your use case, you might not even need to expose a function as you can do it inside the browser itself.